# c++ code magically add 1 to the output

Tags: c++, c, output

So I can't figure this out. (obviously)

Basically the variable count is declared in the beginning, then only modified or incremented in one place. The expected final count is `78682`. And when count is equal to that, I'll print out the string "`ok`". When count is incremented to `78683`, the code checks the condition and prints the string "`not ok`".

It never prints "`not ok`", but at the very end when we print the value of the count, it's `78683`! When did c++ incremented?

Another thing is that when the comment is uncommented below, the final result then becomes `78682`, though I just don't understand why. Anyone? (oh btw, the code takes a minute to run....)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int count=0, sum=0;

int length []={1,2,4,10,20,40,100,200};
int value [] ={200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1};
int tmp[8] ={0};

bool stop=false;

while(!stop){
    sum=0;
    for(int j=0,k=0; j<8; j++){
        sum+=value[j]*tmp[j];
        if(j==7){
            if(sum==200){
                count++;
                if(count==73682) printf("ok\n");

                if(count==73683) printf("not ok\n");
            }

            k=j;
            tmp[k]++;
            while(tmp[k]==length[k]+1){

                tmp[k]=0;
                k--;
                tmp[k]++;

                if(tmp[0]==2) 
                {
                    //tmp[0]--;
                    stop=true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

printf("Total %d.", count);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not `c++`. Quite far away i'd say. Not like it really matters, but still.

Comment: @luk32 Compile it with g++ and run it. It's c++.

Comment: `printf` is *not* c++ and therefore this isn't "pure" c++.

Comment: You must be missing a continue or break statement somewhere.

Comment: "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'tmp' was corrupted." was the result of running your code BTW. But after I stepped past it the output was magically 73682.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my computer I getting

```
ok
Total 73682.
```

both with the line commented and with the line uncommented. Therefore I can't debug it.

But the most probable assumption is that the reason you get wrong result is out-of-bounds array access. If you write `tmp[anything]` it can be any place in memory, including the place where count is stored. So you need to check that `0 <= anything && anything < 8`. You can such an access here:

```
 while(tmp[k]==length[k]+1){

   tmp[k]=0;
   k--;
```

please add safety checks to ensure `k >= 0`.

P.S. I added the check:

```
 while(tmp[k]==length[k]+1){

            tmp[k]=0;
            k--;
            if( k < 0 ) printf("oops\n");
```

with the line commented I get

```
ok
oops
Total 73682.
```

with the line uncommented I get

```
ok
Total 73682.
```

so probably you have some other mistake in the program. Sorry, can't find it. (Also knowing what the program suppose to do you can print intermediate results and check them. But you should see out of bounds access on you computer if you get 73683).

Comment: so the out-of-range array may temper with the variable "count" (at least on my computer)?

Comment: @campuswebber, yes, if you write tmp[-anything] it can be any place in memory, including the place where count is stored.

Comment: This is exactly what happened. Without comment, the while loop runs  one last time and k get -1. tmp[k]++, which made count++. Thanks.